# Parthenogenesis Induction

Tags: evolution, entomology, bacteriology, molecular-evolution, parasitology

I have read about Parthenogenesis induction in a paper : "Hagimori T, Abe Y, Date S, Miura K (2006) The first finding of a Rickettsia bacterium associated
with parthenogenesis induction among insects. Curr Microbiol 52: 97–101 "

I was curious to know what is the evolutionary advantage of parthenogenesis induction for the parasite (in this case Rickettsia bacterium ) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is addressed in [this review by Cordaux et al, 2011](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0168952511000631), along with other, similar strategies.

The simple answer is that these types of bacteria are efficiently spread from females of the species they infect to their offspring; by inducing unfertilized eggs to develop into females, they increase their transmission efficacy.